# Android: using notifyDataSetChanged and getLastVisiblePosition - when the listView is actually updated?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to use getLastVisiblePosition() and apparently it is not giving me the right number after this method (notifyDataSetChanged) has been called. I think this method only notifies the view that there is a change, but the change is triggered later.

When the view is updated, is there an event that I can use and trigger my method, using getLastVisiblePosition?

Please help or tell me what I am doing wrong ;)

Thanks
Danail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you run `notifyDatasetChanged()`, you need to queue the operation in the `post` because the view is rendered asynchronously:

```
     listView.post(new Runnable() { 
       public void run(){ 
         lastPos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
       } 
     });
```