# Android ListView: Detect if ListView data fits on screen without scrolling

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: using notifyDataSetChanged and getLastVisiblePosition - when the listView is actually updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044796/android-using-notifydatasetchanged-and-getlastvisibleposition-when-the-listvi)

I have a simple ListView with only a few entries. Depending on the device size and orientation, the ListView needs to scroll or not.

I have also a picture on the screen, which is not really necessary. I would like to remove the picture if there is not enough space for the ListView without scrolling.

When I fill my ListView in the onCreate of the activity, the getLastVisiblePosition() is not yet valid, it returns -1. Thus I can not compare last visible item to list count.

int lastVisiblePos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); // returns -1

(If I click on a button later to recheck, the value is correct.)

Using the onScrollingListener is too late, as the picture should not be shown in the first place.

I am developing on API level 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to call this method after the listview was initialized and set as a content view?

Comment: Post a `Runnable` on your `ListView` reference and in that `Runnable` use the `getLastVisiblePosition` method.

Comment: The View itself should be ready after setContentView(), however, your listview is truly ready when you finish loading the items into it, you could use it in a thread which was post delayed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044796/android-using-notifydatasetchanged-and-getlastvisibleposition-when-the-listvi

Comment: Thank Kirill, using runnabel returns correct value now.
Unfortunately, the lastVisibleItem return the last partly visible item. So if the last item in the list is not fully shown, I can not recognize it. Different problem.

listView.post(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  int lastVisiblePos = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
  if (lastVisiblePos < listView.getCount()-1){
   final int GONE = 8;
   ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_TitleImage);
   pic.setVisibility(GONE);
  }
listView.getCount());
 }
});

Comment: Comment by Anonymous: Since this question is marked as exact duplicate, I would like to point out that the solution of SAM not only provides the answer on how to get LastVisiblePosition, but also how to identify if the last position is shown fully (not only partly) on the screen, which is vital to the problem stated her.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Compare [`getLastVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) with [`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount%28%29) in a Runnable to see if the entire ListView fits on the screen as soon as it has been drawn. You should also check to see if the last visible row fits entirely on the screen.

Create the Runnable:

```
ListView listView;
Runnable fitsOnScreen = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        if(last == listView.getCount() - 1 && listView.getChildAt(last).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
            // It fits!
        }
        else {
            // It doesn't fit...
        }
    }
};
```

In `onCreate()` queue your Runnable in the ListView's Handler:

```
listView.post(fitsOnScreen);
```

Comment: You're welcome, please click the check mark to accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: @Sam , I have implemented the same method , but it slows down the scrolling, even i can't drag the thumb. Can u help me?

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks !

Comment: If the scroll position can be anywhere use this modified version:


`public boolean doesItFit(ListView listView) {
        int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View firstPosition = listView.getChildAt(first);
        View lastPosition = listView.getChildAt(last);
        return last == listView.getCount() - 1 &&
               first == 0 && last != -1 &&
               firstPosition.getTop() == 0 &&
               lastPosition.getBottom() <= listView.getHeight();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for problems? Instead of your idea you can use 3 layouts:

1. Widgets if necessary - header
2. ListView - main layout
3. ImageView or other widgets  - footer

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.foorer_layout, null);
lv.addHeaderView(headerComment);
lv.addFooterView(footerComment);
```

Comment: I do not see how this solves my problem. As of 1. (Widgets if necessary) I do not know all the possible combinations of screen sizes and densities. I also change textSize depending on those.

Comment: Text size depends on device settings. It's better to use **sp** for text size. sp - Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: If you chose my combination you don't have problems with different combinations of screen sizes and densities.

Comment: I actually do use sp for text sizes. Tests on different devices and densities reveales that some manual optimization has to be done. Your solution makes the picture scrollable, but still the user has to scroll, so it does not achieve my goal. Thanks anyhow for your time.