# How to layout_alignParentBottom if view is bigger in size, otherwise layout_below should be followed

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to know if we can layout_alignParentBottom and layout_below at the same time having the priority for below and if the view is bigger then have the priority of aligning to the bottom of the parent.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/questions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/oneThirtyDP"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/oneThirtyDP">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/img_how_expeirence"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="howaboutfollowing"
            android:textColor="#2c364c"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fiftyTwoSP"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_how_expeirence"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_buttons"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tenDp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fiveDp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_buttons"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tenDp">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_buttons should be below list view if list view is smaller in size (wrap_content) and should align to the bottom of the parent if there are many items in the list view.

Comment: did you try using mListView.canScrollVertically(Direction)

Comment: you can identify scrollview fits in to window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572667/android-listview-detect-if-listview-data-fits-on-screen-without-scrolling

Comment: then if scrolled up then you can set alignment of  layout

Comment: I was looking more towards a solution within xml file rather than code. Code yes I can check and add and delete rules, no problem in that.